# How do i programmatically restart my Spring application in case of an exception?

Tags: java, spring-boot, devtools, applicationcontext, application-restart

I am workign on a spring boot application that from time to time crashed or has some strange connection errors. While it is a different matter if its a good solution to just restart the application in case of an error, i still want this is as a kind of last resort method. Basicly i want to understand how to restart the whole application after each iteration of a loop. I have tried [Baeldungs tutorial on Programmatically Restarting a Spring Boot Application](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-context-events) but the code is not working since in this approach:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    public static void restart() {
        ApplicationArguments args = context.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            context.close();
            context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args.getSourceArgs());
        });

        thread.setDaemon(false);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

context only contains a null value and therefore throws a nullpointer exception. As you can see in the comments i am not the only one having this problem. I also tried the solution from the comment section using the **org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter class**

Here you can basicly see the big loop with my main controller and that it should restart in case any unhandled exception occurs.

```
@Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        try {
            while (true){
                try {
                    mainController.run;
                } catch (Exception | CacheDataException e){
                    log.error("Exception in Main controller");
                    Restarter.getInstance().restart();
                } finally {
                    log.info("Restarting mainController.");
                }
            }
        } finally {
            log.info("Closing the application.");
            this.sshSession.shutdown();
            System.out.println(BananaUtils.bananansi("Tier 2 ends", Ansi.BLUE));
        }
    }
```

If i do that however i get about 1000 exceptions and errors thrown from INSIDE the mainController resulting in endless attempts to restart the application eventually crashing with Overflow errors etc.

Why is it even continuing the loop when it should just restart the application ? What is an elegant way to just simply restart the application. It would even be enough if all the beans get reset. I just want the whole thing to reset itself and start from a new.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: If you are running the spring boot application in a Linux machine, you can have a cron job running every 1 minute, to see if the Spring boot process is running using ps -ef command. if not running issue java -jar springboot-jar... command again to restart from external system. Everything in a shell scriipt.

In windows, the same approach might be possible.

Comment: I want to know how to do it programmatically... thanks anyway.

Comment: If you are running the spring boot application with loadbalancer, probably it addresses High availability. Deploying springboot application in Kubernetes using docker image can also help, where self healing feature of Kubernetes can be utilized to advantage.

Comment: @Tim certainly you don't suggest going for Docker and Kubernetes just to get an app to restart

Comment: hava you checked if context is not null right after you start the app? how do you call this method?

Comment: @eis using kuberentes and docker is an idea. few other example on the internet suggest  more of external program to restart using actuator rather from internal with the application.

Comment: @eis What do you mean how do i call this method ?Its null right after the call of SpringApplication.run()

Comment: @MajesticOl I meant when you call this restart() method and from where. Also, maybe you have put the wrong link in the question, the https://www.baeldung.com/spring-context-events link doesn't seem to contain any of the code you refer to?

Comment: Maybe you meant this link instead: https://www.baeldung.com/java-restart-spring-boot-app

Comment: however, in the comments there it is mentioned that the solution works, it's just that it doesn't work multiple times.